# Suppose $g$ is a continuous map from the 2-sphere to itself such that $g(x)\neq g(-x)$ for all $x$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $g$ is a continuous map from the 2-sphere to itself such that $g(x)\neq g(-x)$ for all $x$. Show that $g$ must be surjective.

I was thinking about using the Borsuk-Ulam thm but it seems not working.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is not surjective, $p$ is not in the image, compose $f$ with the stereographic projection $h$ relatively to $p$ and apply Borsuk Ulam. Borsuk Ulam implies the existence of $x$ such that $h(f(x))=h(f(-x))$ since $h$ is injective, $f(x)=f(-x)$. Contradiction.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! *.*